# Scala Macro Type Args Introspection on Case Class

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-2.13, scala-2.12

I've got a library that generates mappings for case classes at compile-time and it works great, unless I pass in a generic type like: `Foo[Bar]` (see https://github.com/outr/fabric/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala-2/fabric/rw/RWMacros.scala#L32). When I call the Macro with `caseClass[Foo[Baz]]` the `typeSignature` represents `Bar`, not `Baz`. I can see in the `tpe` that that at compile-time it is `Foo[Baz]`, but I can't figure out how to map from the `Bar` generic type to the `Baz` in the `typeArgs` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @zygfryd on Gitter.im! He pointed me to `asSeenFrom` and I was able to update the code with `val returnType = tpe.decl(name).typeSignature.asSeenFrom(tpe, tpe.typeSymbol.asClass)` and now it resolves correctly to the generic type.